# Redirect back with Symfony and twig

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, twig, symfony4

In my Symfony project I have two views. Details view of specific entity and a button to lead me to a new view with with some other data by date param.

The problem with the code I have is of generating 'Return to previous' page button from second method back to first..

Code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/details/{id}", name="first_method")
 */
public function firstMethod(Detail $id)
{
    $workspace = $this->entityManager
        ->getRepository(Detail::class)
        ->find($id);

    $build['detail'] = $detail;

$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('date', DateTimeType::class, [
            'data' => new \DateTime(),
            'widget' => 'single_text'
        ])
        ->add(
            'save',
            SubmitType::class,
            [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'btn-submit']
            ]
        )
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        $date = $data['date']

        return $this->redirectToRoute('second_method', [
            'date' => $date
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('first-method.html.twig', [
          'detail' => $detail,
        ]);
}
```

And there is that 'second' method:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/second-method/{date}", name="second_method")
 */
public function secondMethod($date)
{
    return $this->render('second-method.html.twig', [
        'someData' => $someData,
        'date' => $date,
    ]);
}
```

I have a button on the second_method twig view which needs to return me back to method_one page.

How can accomplish that as the parameter $id is probably needed in second method but can not find a way to provide it. Maybe there is some other way? Can someone help?

I think in this first way it shoud me like:

```
{{ path('first_method', {'detailId':detail.id}) }}
```

Comment: You can either pass the `id` to the `second_method` even if you don't need it just for the purpose of redirecting back (that would change the uri) or maybe be a bit naive and use the `referrer` to redirect back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by @msg, you should provide a second parameter to your second page. You will then need the `@Entity` annotation for `Detail` conversion and the `@ParamConverter` annotation for the date conversion :

```
/**
 * @Route("/second_method/{id_detail}/{date}", name="second_method")
 * @Entity("detail", expr="repository.find(id_detail)")
 * @ParamConverter("date", options={"format": "!Y-m-d"})
 */
public function (Detail $detail, \DateTime $date)
// ...
```

The parameter conversion will perform a first sanity check and will return a `404` if the entity doesn't exist.
You will also be able to check in your controller that `$detail` is coherent with the `date` in the URL. Remember : never trust user input (this includes URLs).

And you can provide this new parameter when your redirect to your second controller :

```
return $this->redirectToRoute("second_method", [
    "date" => $date,
    "id_detail" => $workspace->getId() // You can also pass the whole object and fetch the ID in the template
]);
```

Then in your template :

```
{{ path('first_method', {'id': id_detail}) }}
```

#### Details

For `ParamConverters` you can find more details here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

I personnaly prefer the `@Entity` annotation for conversion of an `Entity` since you are sure of how the conversion is done : I find it better for when your project grows and your entities have more and more parameters. Eventhough the `@ParamConverter` would work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative without changing the `second_method` route parameters, relying only on the referer.

Add the helper method to the controller:

```
/**
 * Returns the referer url to redirect back if the request came from first_method
 * Otherwise returns FALSE.
 */
private function getBackUrl(Request $request, UrlMatcherInterface $matcher)
{
    $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
    if (null === $referer) {
        return false;
    }

    $url = parse_url($referer);
    if ($url['host'] != $request->getHost()) {
        return false;
    }

    // Remove the baseurl if we're in a subdir or there's no Rewrite
    $path = str_replace($request->getBaseUrl(), '', $url['path']);
    try {
        $route = $matcher->match($path);
    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException $e) {
        // Doesn't match any known local route
        return false;
    }

    // A route has been determined, check if it matches the requirement
    if ('first_method' == $route['_route']) {
        return $referer;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Change the method to (The `Route` annotation doesn't change, just the method signature):

```
public function secondMethod($date, Request $request, UrlMatcherInterface $matcher)
{
    return $this->render('second-method.html.twig', [
        'someData' => $someData,
        'date' => $date,
        'back_url' => $this->getBackUrl($request, $matcher),
    ]);
}
```

In your template:

```
{# Show the button only if the request came from first_method (otherwise will be false) #}
{% if back_url %}
     <a class="btn" href="{{ back_url }}">Return</a>
{% endif %}
```